# class style isn't update while the content is

Tags: vue.js

I want to show an icon depending if variable is true or false, so I just made a ternary operator to do this :

```js
getClass(enabled) {
      return enabled ? "fa fa-check" : "fa fa-times";
}
```

I call it like this :

```js
<div slot-scope="{ row }" class="f-flex">
   <i :class="getClass(row.enabled)" />{{ row.enabled }}
</div>
```

It works first (when I load the page)

[image]

but when I change the row.enabled variable, it doesn't work whereas the content is changed

[image]

I also tried to put the entire data into an array like this :

```js
this.dashboards.forEach((d) => {
  this.enabledDashboards[d._id] = d.enabled;
  this.default_range[d._id] = this.ranges.find((r) => r.value == d.default_range).label;
});
```

and now I get the class like this :

```
     <i :class="getClass(row._id)" />{{ enabledDashboards[row._id] }}
</div>

getClass(id) {
      return this.enabledDashboards[id] ? "fa fa-check" : "fa fa-times";
    },
```

But it won't work

Comment: `getClass` looks like it is in `methods` which is not reactive to property changes. You would need to move it into `computed` and also get `enabled` from a reactive property instead of being passed in. Object properties are not typically reactive unless you force them to be.

Comment: I can't move it into computed because I have a parameter..

Comment: Instead of passing in that param, get the property from `this.row.enabled` (or how ever you need to access it) within `getClass`. Accessing it that way allows the reactivity to do its thing.